# Sveltekit: Build working in 'preview' but not when using 'node build'. URL Constructor error

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, vite, sveltekit

Currently wanting to deploy an internal app using Apache2 on Debian. The build is successful and the app works perfectly when running 'npm run preview'. The issue occurs when I'm using 'node build'. I get an error within the browser's console that says "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: URL constructor: 127.0.0.1:4000/api/dashboardtbl is not a valid URL.". I'm thinking it may be an issue with the build target being es2018?

This is the file/code that is making the request to the API:

```
    function requestData() {
        data = [];
        if (!host) return;
        const url = new URL(host + '/api/dashboardtbl');

        url.searchParams.set('page', page.toString());
        url.searchParams.set('pageSize', pageSize.toString());

        if (search) {
            url.searchParams.set('search', search);
        }

        if (Object.keys(filters).length > 0) {
            url.searchParams.set('colFilters', JSON.stringify(filters));
        }

        const dest = url.toString().replace(host, '');
        console.log('dest', dest);
        console.log('host', host);

        fetch(dest)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((res: NOCTableResponse) => {
                data = res.rows;
                // console.log(res.count)
                maxPages = Math.ceil(res.count / pageSize);
                options.update((o) => ({ ...o, data }));
            });
            //  if (data.length < pageSize) {
            //      pageSize = data.length
            // }
    }


    onMount(async () => {
        host = window.location.host;

        requestData();
    });
```

svelte config:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        // adapter-auto only supports some environments, see https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-auto for a list.
        // If your environment is not supported or you settled on a specific environment, switch out the adapter.
        // See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters for more information about adapters.
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};

export default config;
```

I believe the way I'm getting the host or URL may be causing the issues. But again, the site fetches the data and works fine within 'npm run preview'.

I've tried to change he build target to es2020/esnext but only resulted in build errors.

Comment: Apache has various hacks to "forward" the proper host field over its reverse proxy. Although there are examples, in practice Apache config and whatever servers are running behind the reverse proxy to figure out what's correct 'Host' header field and how to read it. You can find 1000+ questions on this on search https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=apache+host+forward

Comment: I support this is not a Svelte problem.  From the message, I see the scheme is missing in your URL.  By looking at your variable, you are using one called "host".  Apache is probably taking it too literal and sending it without the scheme part.  A quick workaround would be to conditionally ensure the scheme is present (http:// or https://).

Comment: See: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node#environment-variables-origin-protocolheader-and-hostheader